# `cp -pr` behaving differently on two different RHEL servers

Tags: linux, scripting, cp, rhel5

I am using a script on RHEL server where I'm copying a backup of the /etc/syslog.conf file before making configurable changes in it. I used the below command in the script:

```
 cp -pr /etc/syslog.conf /etc/syslog.conf.bkp.`date +"%d%m%Y"`
```

The script ran absolutely fine on one RHEL server, but on the other it shows the below error:

```
cp: cannot stat `/etc/syslog.conf': No such file or directory
```

I also checked the /etc/syslog/conf file exists in the server just fine.

Why is the difference of behaviour. How to resolve it ?

Comment: Did you check the permission of that file  for the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cp: cannot stat is mainly because cp command can't see the file. It can be for two reasons.

- File is not present
- You don't have permission to view the file.

If you check these two things you should be able to find the answer